# Use of overloaded function inside template with template param

Tags: c++, templates

Can it be done in a nice way?

```
template <class T> Init(T &object, Type type)
{
    Collider collider;
    switch (type)
    {
    case TypeA:
        collider.InitAsA(object);
        break;
    case TypeB:
        collider.InitAsB(object);
    }
}
```

call with

```
A a;
Init(a, TypeA);
B b;
Init(b, TypeB);
```

A and B have no common ancestor.

```
void Collider::InitAsA(A &a);
void Collider::InitAsB(B &b);
```

EDIT:

Collider::InitAs.. can't be changed into template, and can't be changed at all, for reason i can't change others code.

Type can be int, actually it is an enum.

Comment: What is `Type`? Can you give an example for `Type1` and `Type2`?

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have?

Comment: Why would you want do do that? Can't you just make `Collider::Init` a template?

Comment: Or instead of using templates as suggested by juanchopanza, why not make two overloads of `Collider::init`? One taking an `A` reference, the other a `B` reference?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Maybe `InitAsA` and `InitAsB` implemented differently?

Comment: @Nawaz Then they could be overloaded. No need for templates actually, I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 5):

With your `Init()` function, you can just use function overloading:

```
void Init(A &object)
{
    Collider collider;
    collider.InitAsA(object);
}

void Init(B &object)
{
    Collider collider;
    collider.InitAsB(object);
}
```

However, you could just overload the `Init()` method:

```
void Collider::Init(A &a);
void Collider::Init(B &b);
```

And then, if you still want a template function, it could look like this:

```
template <typename T>
void Init (T &object)
{
    Collider collider;
    collider.Init(object);
}
```